# SPARQL - get list of places in one country

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to SPARQL and would like some help in my learning.
I want to get latitude and longitude of several places (neighborhoods, cities, states, regions, rivers, monuments, ..) of my country: Brazil.

I tried:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT *
WHERE  { 
    ?s a dbo:Place .
    ?s geo:lat ?lat .
    ?s geo:long ?long .
    ?s a ?type .
    ?s a ?city .
    ?s rdfs:label "Rio de Janeiro"@en.
}
limit 10
```

I don't want to restrict my query to just "cities". I want to search for places by various attributes: "city", "river", "village", "mountain", "monuments", "hill", "island", "valley", "point", "peak" ...
Furthermore, I am not restricting the country ...

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks like the one in [Get Place categories from DBpedia using SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352187/get-place-categories-from-dbpedia-using-sparql).

As it stands, your query is not limited to cities - it is just limited to `dbo:Place`s that have the English name (label) "Rio de Janeiro". `?city` is a variable; its name doesn't do anything special.

If you want any place, just remove the above mentioned triple patterns.

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT *
WHERE  { 
  ?s a dbo:Place .
  ?s geo:lat ?lat .
  ?s geo:long ?long .
  ?s a ?type .
}
limit 10
```

This gets you 10 places with latitude and longitude and another class. You could browse DBpedia to [see what kinds of places there are](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place), decide whether you need `dbo:Location_(feature)` too and try subclasses of Place, Location too (as per [DBpedia, getting the direct or indirect types of Place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672546/dbpedia-getting-the-direct-or-indirect-types-of-place)). To filter for country, you could add to your query

```
  ?s dbo:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brazil> .
```

But not every place will have an explicit link to the country like this. You'll have to see what properties can help out with linking a place to its country.