# DBpedia, getting the direct or indirect types of Place

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I want to get only the direct or indirect subclass of `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place`

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ?type,?label WHERE {
         :Mauritius rdf:type ?type .
         ?type rdfs:label ?label .
         FILTER (LANG(?label)='en')
    }
```

The query above works. However it returns me different result of different types. I want to restrict the types only as a direct or indirect subclass of `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place`,

is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

Great, got it, 
use `rdfs:subClassOf` and don't forget the `*` to make it `rdfs:subClassOf*`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?type,?label WHERE {
     :Mauritius rdf:type ?type .
     ?type rdfs:label ?label .
     ?type rdfs:subClassOf* dbpedia-owl:Place .
     FILTER (LANG(?label)='en')
}
```